# Pass parameter from JUnit 5 @BeforeEach to individual test

Tags: java, junit, junit5

Say I have a `@BeforeEach` method which uses an external method to get a value and set something up with said value:

```java
@BeforeEach
void foo() {
  int bar = getBarFromSomething();
  setupSomethingWithBar(bar);
}
```

Now, I want to be able to pass the value of `bar` (which may change every time `getBarFromSomething()` is called) to each individual test case after the `foo()` method is called before the test case. I want to do this so that I can test something using the parameter which I setup in the `@BeforeEach foo()` method call:

```java
@Test
void test_baz(int bar) {
  assertEquals(bar, 5);
}
```

How would I go about passing a parameter from the `@BeforeEach foo()` call to each individual `@Test` case? I don't think that parameterized tests will work since the method which generates `bar` may output different results so it needs to be called only once per `@BeforeEach` and `@Test` case run and it needs to be used to set something up in the `foo()` call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just move the method variable to a member variable... like this:

```
int bar = getBarFromSomething();
@BeforeEach
void foo() {
    setupSomethingWithBar(bar);
}
```

Then

```
@Test
void test_baz() {
    assertEquals(bar, 5);
}
```

Should work

Comment: I could do this while actually calling `getBarFromSomething()` inside the `@BeforeEach` invocation since I need to call it once per test case, but I'm unsure if there's a better "JUnit practice" to do this where I don't have to touch the test class state.

Answer (score 2):

There is no junit-specific facility to empower your idea.

Unless you use *@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)*, new instance of a test class will be created for each test call. That means, @Bill K is right, and you are welcome to initialize a test class field.

But the better way is to use [parametrized test](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.5.2/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests) with [@MethodSource](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.5.2/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-sources-MethodSource) and performing *setup* right in the test somewhere in the *given* section. This is precisely the task @ParametrizedTests are intended to solve.

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class TestSample {

   @ParameterizedTest
   @MethodSource("bars")
   fun isFive(bar:Int){
       setupSomethingWithBar(bar)  
       assertEquals(bar, 5)
   }

   fun bars() = (1..10).asSequence().asStream()
}
```

Comment: The thing is, I need to use the _same_ output of `bars` in both the `@BeforeEach` setup method and the test itself. So, in your example, assuming the `bars` method returns a bar which is random, I would have to call `bars()` to get a random bar in the `@BeforeEach` call, and then I would have to somehow pass that _same_ bar into `isFive` since if I call `bars` again I would get a different bar. That is why I cannot use parameterized tests as far as I know.

Comment: the idea was not to use @beforeEach for test-specific setups (it is designed to do general preparations), but perform this test-specific setup directly in the test body.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. I could definitely do that but it seems quite inconvenient given that the `@BeforeEach` method is intended to be common setup between tests but in this case I can't use it.